# How to make if statement on empty list in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, email, if-statement

I have a small problem with creating an if statement in python. I am compering two csv files using Panda Library and I want to create an if statement which will be checking if list is empty. So this is my code

```
file1 = pd.read_csv('otomotofirst.csv')
file2 = pd.read_csv('otomotonew.csv')

change=(file2[~file2.Linki.isin(file1.Linki)])

if change is None:
    break
else:
    send_mail(subjectNew,change)
```

It is working quite well, however if it is empty (or in my case None) email is also sent. Of course it sends an empty list but it doesn't break.

I was trying do it with True and False statement but this error always pop ups

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: A dataframe behaves differently from a list when it comes to truthiness and falsiness. You can use `change.shape[0]` or `len(change)` to check if the length is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a list, you have a DataFrame. DataFrames, even empty, **are not** `None`.

```
pd.DataFrame() is None
False
```

You check if a DataFrame is empty with the `empty` attribute.

```
pd.DataFrame().empty
True
```

Regarding the error, you can't treat a DataFrame like a list to check emptiness

```
if []: print(True)              # Works 
if pd.DataFrame(): print(True)  # ValueError
```

---

The code should be

```
if change.empty:
    break
else:
    send_mail(subjectNew, change)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `os.path.getsize()` in order to obtain the size of a file.
So, if you wnat to check if your file is empty:

```
filesize = os.path.getsize("file.csv")
filesize1 = os.path.getsize("file1.csv")

def file_compare():
  if(filesize == 0 and filesize == 0):
      print("Both files are empty")
  if(filesize == filesize1):
      print("File sizes are equal", str(filesize)
  else:
      print(str(filesize))
      print(str(filesize1))`
```

Hope it works!

Comment: It is not what I was looking for but still thank you very much